# Which parts of Cyborg are under the control of his defense system?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe

In the Justice League (2017) Cyborg and the other members meet Superman who doesn't recognize them. Then Cyborg says something and his arm starts to move on its own automatically, trying to fire at Superman and it does it. He tries to stop his arm to do this with his other arm.

Now I thought the dialogue was

> It's my arms defense system. It's stronger since the interface. I
> can't control it.

But I found some people quoting it is

> It's my arm's defense system. It's stronger since the interface. I
> can't control it.

Now if it was only his left arm which was in control of his defense system, why didn't he just turn around? Or is it actually the first quote the correct one and it's his arms defense system which is stronger since the interface?

Which parts of Cyborg are under the control of his defense system?

Comment: Arm or a misheard ARMOR?

Comment: The quotes I found say arm. You say it could be armor defense system?

Comment: Just asking the question. I usually find there is a screenplay somewhere online. Worth a search.

Comment: @Paulie_D this links claims armor as you said https://screenrant.com/zack-snyder-justice-league-knightmare-plan/2/

Comment: Notice Arms Defense System is also a real life military term